# How to de-clutter MMa-SE to ease searching?

Tags: feature-request

Earlier today, had a file go corrupt

The WR documentation gave a solution that didn't work. So I posted this Question:

[How to restore corrupted files?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92814/how-to-restore-corrupted-files)

In the first Comment, @belisarius posted a link to pertinent Search results. I clicked through every link, which led me to several un-Answered Questions, an Answer that didn't work, and several links to the worthless WR doc I'd already seen.

And then @Lou gave me a two-line fix that worked perfectly. My joy was great.

So now, if someone searches SE for "restore corrupt file" they will EVENTUALLY find my Question and @Lou's Answer, but they will probably first waste some time plowing through all the same unhelpful stuff I plowed through.  Is there anyway to clear out all that clutter and direct users efficiently to the right Answer?

Comment: I have not explored this group of questions yet but it sounds like, if possible, a number of them should be closed as duplicates.  If there are other good methods scattered about other Q&A's ideally these should be Merged to collect all good methods into one place.

Comment: Repeat the search I gave you. Order the results by votes. Voilà!

Comment: We have all experienced the stress of almost loosing a file and the frustration when a proposed solution fails. I'm sorry my solution did not work for you, but it performs several useful operations on the file and from the voting at least 2 people appreciated it enough to vote it up. My point is that in being too rigorous in cleaning out answers that didn't work in a specific situation you might be deleting solutions that work just fine in others, and limiting the variety of alternative approaches.